# What happened to most of my icons?

Tags: windows, windows-8, windows-8.1, icons

What happened to most of my icons? Most programs and even just plain text files or word files have lost their icons. I haven't installed any weird crap, and I don't have any viruses/malware.

How can I fix this?[image: Desktop view, most icons not showing, except for a few.]

Answer (score 1):

You could try refreshing the IconCache database:

1. Click Start --> Computer.
2. Click Organize (on the Tool bar) --> Folder and Search Options.
3. Then click the View tab, and check-mark the Show hidden files and folders option, and click OK.
4. Navigate to the following directory:

`C:\Users\(Your User Name)\AppData\Local`

5. Find the IconCache.db file, and rename it (say IconCache.old) or delete it.
6. Close the window, and restart the computer.

Windows will recreate the IconCache after you reboot and hopefully everything will be fixed.